# match all query against elastic search index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Looking at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html#unstructured-search), I am wondering, if it is also possible to search an index simply by a string, e.g.:

```
Hello World
```

and receive data not bound to an explicit entity. Some pseudo code:

```
 var searchResponse = client.Search(MatchAllQuery ...?, index=someIndex, q="Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(sd => sd
    .Index("index_name")
    .Type("type")
    .Size(10000)
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m.Field("TextID").Query("Hello World")
        )));
```

Comment: Thanks but Document is a POCO that must exist right?

Comment: Yes! I'm afraid that can't be skipped.